# How to truncate the leading zeros when using syscall to print binary/hex in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I have this code that converts decimal to binary using syscall :

```
.text 

main:

    li $v0, 35
    li $a0, 3
    syscall
```

which convert 3 to a binary. This is the output :

```
00000000000000000000000000000011
```

And this is to print Hex :

```
0x00000003
```

But I want to truncate the leading zeros in binary and hex. Any idea how? I also want to remove the 'x' from the hex

Comment: You will need to do the conversion yourself.

Comment: @Jester you mean the conversion from decimal to bin and decimal to hex? so I can manipulate the actual string?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: The only conversion you need to do yourself is from binary integer (in a register) to string using some base.  You can still use MARS system call for input (from decimal string or whatever).  When you said decimal, maybe you meant a number in a register?  But computers including MIPS use binary, that's why left shift by 1 multiplies by 2 with simple hardware.  Debuggers usually print register values as hex and/or decimal, but in the CPU they're binary.

Answer (score 1):

In short, there's no way to do this kind of formatting using MARS/QtSpim syscalls.

I'm surprised we don't have a standard answer for this!

The MARS environment appears to be designed to allow simple programming easily, but is far from complete and virtually uncustomizable, so you get to write code for doing things like that.

In another environment, we could imaging printing to a string (or to a file) for post processing, like removing leading zeros, but not here. Those print functions only go to the console, so there's no way to capture their output and re-process.

In another environment, we would have general purpose formatting capabilities, like `printf`, but again, not here. These simulators have no standard libraries, either, so the syscalls are all we get.

And there's no reason for these simulators to do more as they target teaching.

Comment: I think we do have some manual conversion MIPS questions.  Not specifically about omitting leading zeros, but some natural ways to loop don't produce leading zeros in the first place.  e.g. [Saving integers as Strings in MIPS](//stackoverflow.com/q/2934126) .  There are at least 2 other such questions with answers that are less efficient (e.g. using `div` twice instead of taking quotient and remainder, or using "push" / "pop" as a way to reverse instead of decrementing a pointer as they store bytes).  In reverse: [Convert String of ASCII digits to int in MIPS](//stackoverflow.com/q/15940331)